# How can I add public key to keyring?

Tags: gnupg, openpgp

I get a public key via form and store it in a temp file. How can I use gpg2 utility to read key from file and add it to keyring?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working but not sure if this is the correct way. `gpg2 --import' + ' ' + tempFile)`. Tempfile have public key.